# Qt package and configure.user file in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: omnet++

I am trying to install OMNET++5.0 on ubuntu 16.04, however, it requires to comment the WITH_QTENV=no in the configure.user file. Where is this file located inside ubuntu ?

Answer (score 1):

`configure.user` is in the main directory of extracted `OMNeT++` package.